# "port 22: Broken pipe" on IPSec VPN(Forticlient) and VMware NAT

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, vmware, vmware-workstation

Currently I am trying to pass my Windows 10 Fortigate VPN connection to a Fedora 29 Workstation VM(VMware workstation 15), and connect over SSH to machines on that VPN. I am able to ping the machines, but when I try connect via SSH, I immediately get disconnected from the server with the general error "port 22: broken pipe". ssh -vvv shows the following:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 6 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env IMSETTINGS_INTEGRATE_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN
debug3: Ignored env IMSETTINGS_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT_PATH
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug1: Sending env XMODIFIERS = @im=none
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_PATH
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PS1
debug3: Ignored env CINNAMON_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env GCC_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: send packet: type 1
packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Broken pipe
```

Have tried using NAT, and Bridged connection to solve this. Bridge does not seem to ever connect correctly, and NAT connects, gives me the public IP of the VPN, but then I get this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the remote server is having trouble starting a shell to handle your session. The shell program may not exist, or it may be failing to start executing, or it may be exiting right away for some reason.

Comment: I acutally finally figured out that it was an issue with VMWare and the QoS flag. By adding the following to my ssh_config:
`IPQoS=throughput`
I was able to correct it!